# Mutithreading and concurrent processing

Tags: multithreading, executorservice, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a small question on mutlithreading.

-I want to start to a thread after some successful pre validations. 
 -If the pre validation fails, there will not be any thread created and the 
 control is sent back to the user with some error message.
 - **If the validation is successful, then i need to send user a success response like a pop with msg "request accepted" and in parallel the thread should be executed.
 - Once the thread is executed, each thread returns some response and
   the response is sent as an email.
 - **The tricky part here is, how can i return a success response back to the user and execute the thread in parallel.
 -**FYI, i am using executor framework for submitting the task and retrieving the response in future object and email the data in future object.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: how do you get the request?

Comment: Its a rest service call. It is called from angular code

Comment: You are right that you have to use an executor service . You should use a CompletableFuture. The beauty of it is that you can attach a callback which will get the result of the task submitted to the threadPool.

Comment: This is a good article.
http://www.deadcoderising.com/java8-writing-asynchronous-code-with-completablefuture/